# Onclick infobox - bing map api

Tags: javascript, hta, bing-maps

I'm having trouble getting the infoboxes for the bing API to open on click from outside the map.

Here is the show infobox function and the function to create the pin/infobox itself:

```
function displayInfobox(e) {
pinInfobox.setOptions({
title: e.target.Title,
description: e.target.Description,
visible: true,
offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 25)
});

pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
}

function hideInfobox(e) {
pinInfobox.setOptions({
visible: false
});
}

function displayPinsOnMap(results) {
// Creates a collection to store multiple pins
var pins = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();

//Create the info box for pushpin
var infoboxOptions = {width: 260, height:160};
pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), infoboxOptions);
infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);

// Create Pins
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
//pushpin location
var position = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(results[i]["Lat"], results[i]["Lon"]);
//Create the pin
if(results[i]["DNC"] == 'DNC') {
var sppins = {htmlContent:"<img src='badsp.png' height='32px'> " };
} else {
var sppins = {htmlContent:"<img src='sppin.png' height='32px'> " };
}
var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(position, sppins);
pin.Title = results[i]["Business Name"];
pin.Description =results[i]["Address"] + "<br>" + 
  results[i]["City"] + ", " +
  results[i]["StateListing"] + "<br>" + 
  results[i]["Phone"] +
  "<br>Fax: " + results[i]["Fax"] +
  "<br>Email: " + results[i]["Email"];

Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);

function pinclick(i) {
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(results[i], 'click');
}

//Add pin to the map
map.entities.push(pin);
}

//hide box on map move
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchange', hideInfobox);


//add pins/infobox
map.entities.push(pinInfobox);
}
```

I have a list of items pulled from a JSON file and displayed on the map. Each item creates a pin and info box as well as in a table off to the side of the map. What I need to be able to do is on click of the name of the company from the table I need it to open up the infobox associated with that company. Here is how I did it in the past with Google API - this doesn't seem to work in the same way for Bing (yes I have to use bing).

```
"<td>"+'<a href="#" onclick="javascript:displayInfobox(' + (i) + ');">' + results[i]["Business Name"] +'<\/a>' + "</td>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have copied the displayInfobox function from some code that is expecting to be trigerred when someone clicks a pushpin because that function has this code:

pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());

the getLocation() method exists on Bing Maps pushpin object but obviously not on your  so it will be failing when it gets to that line (your using your browsers debug tools right?). You will need to change that line so that it gets the location for the infobox to show from somewhere, either by having the lat lon as some attribute on your  and constructing a new Bing Maps location object using those or by looping through all the pins on the map to find that one that matches your  in some way

Comment: ah you know I didn't think of that. That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help!